# XSLT: for-each-group select with condition - not(contains())

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements, contains

I would like to get help with my problem in creating an xslt transform.
I need to get select from xsl:for-each-group with some conditions.
I need to get all elements, which sub-element have text in sub-element "Zkrat" not same as text in this array

```
<xsl:variable name="zkratky">
      <zkratka>1</zkratka>
      <zkratka>2</zkratka>
      <zkratka>5</zkratka>
      <zkratka>6</zkratka>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='zkratky']"/>
```

My XML file input is:

```
<MoneyData>
    <SeznamObjPrij>
        <ObjPrij>
            <Polozka>
                <KmKarta>
                    <Popis>Main title</Popis>
                    <TypKarty>komplet</TypKarty>
                    <Slozeni>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item1</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>2</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>1111</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>1</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item2</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>1</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>22222</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>4</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item3</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>3</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>1111</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>1</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                    </Slozeni>
                </KmKarta>
            </Polozka>
            <Polozka>
                <KmKarta>
                    <Popis>Test</Popis>
                    <TypKarty>jednoducha</TypKarty>
                </KmKarta>
            </Polozka>
            <Polozka>
                <KmKarta>
                    <Popis>Main title</Popis>
                    <TypKarty>komplet</TypKarty>
                    <Slozeni>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item1</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>2</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>1111</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>10</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item2</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>2</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>33333</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>1</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item3</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>1</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>1111</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>2</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                        <Komponenta>
                            <KmKarta>
                                <Popis>Subtitle Item4</Popis>
                                <Zkrat>3</Zkrat>
                                <Katalog>4444</Katalog>
                            </KmKarta>
                            <PocMj>1</PocMj>
                        </Komponenta>
                    </Slozeni>
                </KmKarta>
            </Polozka>
        </ObjPrij>
    </SeznamObjPrij>
</MoneyData>
```

My xslt transform:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Polozka/KmKarta/Slozeni/Komponenta[$lookup[not(contains(., KmKarta/Zkrat))]]" group-by="KmKarta/Katalog">
       <xsl:sort select="KmKarta/Popis"/>
       <tr>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="KmKarta/Popis"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="KmKarta/Zkrat"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/PocMJ)"/></td>
       </tr>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

I always get all elements or none. Or this message:
Wrong occurrence to match required sequence type
Error location: xsl:stylesheet / xsl:template / div / table / tbody / xsl:for-each-group / @select
Details
XPTY0004: The parameter value ('4' item(s)) at position '1' of the 'contains' function has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')

Please, help me.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of things wrong here.

Firstly, if you're using `for-each-group` then you're using XSLT 2.0+ which means you don't need the contortion of having the stylesheet read its own global variables using document('').

There are several problems in this expression

```
Komponenta[$lookup[not(contains(., KmKarta/Zkrat))]]
```

As written, the context item for evaluating `KmKarta/Zkrat` is an element in $lookup, which isn't what you want.

And I don't think you need `contains()` here - you need "=" which makes it much simpler.

So I think you just want `Komponenta[not(KmLarta/Zkrat = $zkratky/zkratka)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use

```
<xsl:variable name="zkratky">
      <zkratka>1</zkratka>
      <zkratka>2</zkratka>
      <zkratka>5</zkratka>
      <zkratka>6</zkratka>
</xsl:variable>
```

plus

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="Polozka/KmKarta/Slozeni/Komponenta[not($zkratky/zkratka = KmKarta/Zkrat)]" group-by="KmKarta/Katalog">
```